# Turn on strict math for LESS compiler in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I'm using the [Web Essentials extension](http://vswebessentials.com/) for Visual Studio 2012. This makes compiling LESS to CSS super easy, maybe too easy – I don't know where compiler options are set.

I would like to turn on strict math mode, but I can't find where to specify this compiler option when using Visual Studio 2012.  (LESS compile support in Visual Studio 2012 comes from [Web Tools 2012.2](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20122-release-notes-rtw).)

These are the LESS options that Web Essentials lets me set:

[image: Visual Studio Options Window]

How do I enable strict math mode when compiling LESS to CSS using Visual Studio 2012 (with Web Tools 2012.2 and Web Essentials)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the manual way ... :-)

Find lessc.wsf, by default in:
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\<some random hash>\Resources\Scripts\lessc.wsf

find this line

```
var css = tree.toCSS({
    compress: args.compress
});
```

change it to

```
var css = tree.toCSS({
    compress  : args.compress,
    strictMath: true        
});
```

Save & Enjoy !

But the long-term solution is to probably file a feature request with the WebEssentials team and ask them to make this optional https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013

Comment: This is great, thanks! I forked the repo and patched it with changes that get the functionality into Web Essentials and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2012/pull/13). I'll give you the bounty unless someone comes forward with an existing way to do it that doesn't require a hack or a patch.

Comment: Oh dang, i didn't see they put WE2012 on Github, last time i looked only 2013 was up :-) Cool ..my VS2013 trial will expire soon !